# Delay going back in NavigationViewcontroller views in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have many views in a `NavigationViewController`. They work fine when they have set a color as background. But when I add an image as background with

```
UIView.addBackground(image)
```

the transitions when I push back button don't go fluid. I have tried even with 3kb images and it happens the same.

Comment: Could you please give some more details. What are you doing to dismiss each controller?

Comment: @Welton122 hmm I'm only pushing ViewControllers forward but doing anything to go back previous view.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example. I'm struggling understand your setup.

Comment: make sure you're not segueing back. it can be very inefficient. Use the built in back button on nav bar

Comment: @Welton122 I have few views embebed in a `NavigationViewControler`. I push programmatically forward with
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
each one. And automatically it creates back buttons, so I don't dismiss each controller manually.